# Need help in exploding multiple arrays and then use foreach to return data

Tags: php

Here are my `variables`

```
<?php
    $submenu = array( array("submenu1", "submenu2", "submenu3", "submenu4"),
           array("submenuA", "submenuB", "submenuC", "submenuD"),
           array("submenuI", "submenuII", "submenuIII", "submenuIV")
    );

    $mainmenu="Main1, Main2, Main3";
?>
```

The desired `output` should be:

```
Main1
 submenu1
 submenu2
 submenu3
 submenu4

Main2
 submenuA
 submenuB
 submenuC
 submenuD

Main3
 submenuI
 submenuII
 submenuIII
 submenuIV
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $submenu = array( array("submenu1", "submenu2", "submenu3", "submenu4"),
           array("submenuA", "submenuB", "submenuC", "submenuD"),
           array("submenuI", "submenuII", "submenuIII", "submenuIV")
         );

    $mainmenu="Main1, Main2, Main3";
    $mainmenu=explode(", ",$mainmenu);
    $tree=array_combine($mainmenu,$submenu);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($tree as $menuname=>$childArray)
    {
        echo "$menuname\n";
        foreach($childArray as $submenuname)
        {
            echo " $submenuname\n";
        }
    }
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
<pre>Main1
 submenu1
 submenu2
 submenu3
 submenu4
Main2
 submenuA
 submenuB
 submenuC
 submenuD
Main3
 submenuI
 submenuII
 submenuIII
 submenuIV
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $submenu = array( array("submenu1", "submenu2", "submenu3", "submenu4"),
        array("submenuA", "submenuB", "submenuC", "submenuD"),
        array("submenuI", "submenuII", "submenuIII", "submenuIV")
    );
    $mainmenu="Main1, Main2, Main3";
    $mainArr=explode(',',$mainmenu);
    $newArr=array_combine($mainArr,$submenu);
    print_r($newArr);   
?>
```

You can test it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

**Output:**

```
Array ( [Main1] => Array ( [0] => submenu1 [1] => submenu2 [2] => submenu3 [3] => submenu4 ) 
[ Main2] => Array ( [0] => submenuA [1] => submenuB [2] => submenuC [3] => submenuD ) 
[ Main3] => Array ( [0] => submenuI [1] => submenuII [2] => submenuIII [3] => submenuIV ) )
```

Comment: Should be exploding on `', '` to get rid of the leading space. Also much easier to use `array_combine`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
// Make your main menu an array
$mainMenuArray = preg_split("/, /", $mainmenu);

// Loop on the main menu
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($mainMenuArray) ; $i++)
{
    // print main menu entry
    echo $mainMenyArray[$i];

    // Print all sub menu linked to the current main menu entry
    foreach($submenu[$i] as $subMenuEntry)
        echo $subMenuEntry;

    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: `$mainMenyArray = preg_split("/, /", $mainmenu);` should be:
`$mainMenuArray = preg_split("/, /", $mainmenu);` you spelled it wrong. Also  `echo $mainMenyArray;` should be  `echo $mainMenuArray[$i];` Next time test your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$submenu = array( array("submenu1", "submenu2", "submenu3", "submenu4"),
       array("submenuA", "submenuB", "submenuC", "submenuD"),
       array("submenuI", "submenuII", "submenuIII", "submenuIV")
     );

$mainmenu="Main1, Main2, Main3";

$main = explode(',', $mainmenu);

for($i=0; $i<count($main); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($submenu); $j++){
        $array[$main[$i]][$j] = $submenu[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

`$array` now contains what you need.

Comment: Not quite. The second mainmenu item will have leading space `" Main2"` and the third will be `" Main3"`. Could have used `$array=array_combine($main,$submenu);` to accomplish the same thing instead of using two ugly-looking for-loops. Also isn't formatting `$array` to the original poster's desired output.

Comment: You're right about formatting the output to desired outcome, however the main thing here is to get them in the correct form and order. Otherwise who would want menus and submenus to be a string of characters?? Obviously it's there to show how it should be ordered (i.e. main menus followed by submenus each)